# Is it possible to use the instance defined in C++/CLI class in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

In the C++/CLI, I have defined some instance in the class as follow.

```
public ref class A
{
public:
    int test(){return 0;}
};

public ref Class B
{
public:
    static A^ a_Instance = gcnew A();

};
```

And in the C# side, I have create a B instance in order try to use the function in a_Instance as follow.

```
private B b_instance = new B();
```

The question is, if it is possible for me to get the instance create in the managed C++ class and use the function in it?

Comment: What makes you think it's not possible? Did you have any problems or did you encounter any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example code that illustrâtes how you can do this. First, define your managed classes (mark them as ref and public). This should be compiled in a C++/CLI project.

```
// CCLI.h
#pragma once
using namespace System;
namespace CCLI {

    public ref class A
    {
    public:
        int test(){return 0;}
    };

    public ref class B
    {
    public:
        static A^ a_Instance = gcnew A();
    };
}
```

Then, add the assembly as reference to the C# project, and you may use the elements this way:

```
namespace CSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CCLI.B b_instance = new CCLI.B();

            CCLI.B.a_Instance.test();
        }
    }
}
```

Two details: the instance of A that is used in C++/CLI is through a static field, hence you want to refer to it statically. Also, you want to make sure that if you compile your C++/CLI for a given architecture (32 or 64 bits), the dot net assembly that uses it is launched in the appropriate architecture (x86 or x64).